# Flip a Coin 100 times - Heads then Tails

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

If I flip a fair coin 100 times, and each time I get a heads immediately followed by tails, I win $5. How much am I expected to win during the game?

---

I know that the probability of getting a head = probability of getting a tail = $\frac{1}{2}$, so the probability of a heads then a tails = $\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4}$. But this is the same probability as any combination of two flips (i.e. two heads, two tails, or tails then a heads). So how can I determine how many of the desired combination would be expected in 100 flips?

Comment: Did you try if you flip it 10 times ?

Comment: I think you will spot the pattern if you work it out for  a few numbers smaller than $100$.

Comment: Recall that expected value is linear... that is $E[X+Y]=E[X]+E[Y]$ as well as $E[\alpha X]=\alpha E[X]$.  This is true *regardless* whether or not $X$ and $Y$ were independent or not.  Now... if $X_i$ is the random variable equal to $5$ if flip $i$ is a head and $i+1$ is a tails and zero otherwise... you have your total amount won is $X=X_1+X_2+\dots+X_{99}$.  Can you finish?

Comment: Note that actually finding a probability distribution to describe the probability of having won a certain amount of money is completely unnecessary to solving the exact question asked here and is largely seen as a waste of time, there being the much simpler and much faster approach alluded to above.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ the Bernoulli process (1: head, 0: tail), you can define the profit Y as:
$$Y=5\sum_{n=2}^{100}\mathbf{1}\{X_n=0,X_{n-1}=1\}$$
Then, the expectation is:
$$\mathbf{E}[Y]=5\sum_{n=2}^{100}\mathbf{P}(X_n=0,X_{n-1}=1)=5\times\frac{99}{4}=123.75$$

Comment: How did you get the $\frac{99}{4}$? Is it that you have a $\frac{1}{4}$ probability of that combination, repeated for 99 pairs of flips?

Comment: Yes, random variables $X_n$ and $X_{n-1}$ are independent so the probability is $\frac{1}{4}$. There are $99$ random variables instead of $100$ because the sum starts in $n=2$.

Answer (score 1):

This is equivalent to lining up $100$ balls where each  ball can be black or white with equal probability, then you win $5 for each black ball that was followed immediately by white ball.

Place a stick between adjacent balls with different color. For each space between adjacent balls, the probability of stick placed on it is $0.5$. Thus the expected number of sticks is $0.5\times 99=49.5$. Because of symmetry, half of these sticks are between black followed by white and the other half are between white followed by black. Therefore the expected winnings are:

$$
0.5\times 99\times 0.5\times $5=$123.75
$$